Give permission for AWS CloudWatch to Invoke a Lambda Function
I need to give a CloudWatch alarm permission to invoke a Lambda function:
This is what I was trying inside the Configuration of the Lambda function:

It seems to be complaining that the ARN is not valid.  I copied it from the alarm directly.  But it seems to want the ARN of a user account?  I don't see any user under which CloudWatch runs.  So what account or role would I pick?  Do I have to assign an account or role to the CloudWatch Alarm, or does it already have one - and if so, how do I find it?

Just after I posted here, I saw the issue.
There are three boxes to choose from, I needed to select "AWS Service" instead of "AWS Account".

